# Best Practices for Modifying Nested Objects in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, object

I'm working on a Python project using Beanie ODM to interact with MongoDB, and I've come across a situation where I need to modify nested objects. Specifically, I'm dealing with a User object that contains a nested Job object (among other attributes). Here's a simplified version of the models I'm working with:

```
from beanie import Document
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Job(BaseModel):
    title: str
    salary: int

class User(Document):
    name: str
    age: int
    job: Job
```

After retrieving a `User` instance from the database, I have several functions that modify both the `User` and its nested `Job` object. For example, updating a user's job title and salary. Now here is where I get a bit uncertain, let's take the following example:

```
from typing import Union
from beanie import init_beanie
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
import asyncio

async def fetch_user_by_name(name: str) -> Union[User, None]:
    user = await User.find_one(User.name == name)
    return user

def update_user_name(user: User, new_name: str) -> None:
    user.name = new_name

def update_user_job(user: User, new_title: str, new_salary: int) -> None:
    user.job.title = new_title
    user.job.salary = new_salary

async def main():
    # Initialize Beanie with database connection and document models
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    await init_beanie(database=client.db_name, document_models=[User])

    # Example usage
    user = await fetch_user_by_name("Alice")
    if user:
        update_user_name(user, "Alice Updated")
        update_user_job(user, "Senior Developer", 90000)
        await user.save()
        print("User and job updated successfully.")
    else:
        print("User not found.")
```

This is a very basic example, the real example is more complex with more methods to manipulate the data based on dependencies and all that.

So, here's where I'm uncertain: I know modifying objects in place can lead to unexpected behavior, especially in a larger codebase or in multi-threaded environments. However, since Beanie returns objects that I then manipulate, I'm pondering the best approach to handle such modifications.

Questions:

- Is it considered bad practice to modify these nested objects in place after retrieving them with Beanie ODM? I'm concerned about potential side effects or the impact on code maintainability.
- Would it be better to create a deepcopy of the object before making modifications? This seems like it would avoid unintended side effects, but I'm worried about the performance impact, especially with more complex or deeper nested objects. I could also just give the object as parameter, modify it and return it, but it's already modified in place so it doesn't make sense to return that one.

What would be considered better practice and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any fatal flaw here. This is exactly what classes are for: bundling related actions and attributes together in a stateful manner to increase readability.

However, if you still feel icky about this, or find it complicates your tests, you could consider refactoring using **dependency injection** ([ref 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#:%7E:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20dependency%20injection,opposed%20to%20creating%20them%20internally.), [ref 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpMGEhwuuyA)). This will force you to pass around `User` and `Job` instances separately, reducing the coupling between them.

Alternatively, you could maintain a `Registry` class which maps `User`s to `Job`s and vice-versa using a hashmap (assuming each `User` and `Job` has a unique ID). With this pattern, your `update_*` functions would only need the `Registry` instance and the relevant IDs as arguments. Of course now you have a third classes to maintain, but there would be no dependency at all between the `User` and `Job` classes.

As always, it's a balancing act between coupling and cohesion. No solution is perfect.

Comment: I think the decoupling is a bit hard, as they are nested stored in the database for reasons. Decoupling them would require more database queries as well, right? My main point was that it feels horrible to pass around mutable objects, because this can cause ugly side-effects. And having each function to get the object from the database and write it back feels aweful as well. Creating a copy of each object when passing to a function and return the result, doesn't feel nice either. I get what you are saying but I don't feel the fit into my example really.

Comment: I think the main issue is that we are dealing with dataclasses that contain a deeper hierarchy. I'm afraid the codebase will become hard to manage if we keep them mutable.

Comment: On the other hand, that might be the whole idea behind encapsulation in OOP and perhaps I should just have getters/setters in place for pydantic. Perhaps my head's is a bit of a mess with all the information to chose from. Sorry about that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It could require more queries. But if your DB is relational, you may just need smarter queries, not more; one query that joins users and jobs and returns the records you need.

Comment: Also, I don't see where you are "creating a copy of each object when passing to a function". The nice thing about mutability is that you don't need to create copies.

Comment: IMHO though, your code is fine as it is. If it makes you uneasy, maybe you should just be doing all your CRUD directly in the DB using SQL. See if a library like `sqlite` or `sqlalchemy` could help bridge the gap for you.

Comment: Thank you for thinking along! We don't use SQL by the way but MongoDB (Beanie is an ODM, much like SQLAlchemy is an ORM for SQL). But thanks for helping me out. I guess we stick with the mutable objects in that case :) I read clean code by uncle bob and everything, but the main concern in my case is that we use dataclasses (pydantic). It really confuses me so now and then about what's recommended (before the codebase becomes tooo big to change).